# Why does the same url work against the facebook graph api in browser or postman but not in my python script?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Why when I use the Graph API in the Graph API Explorer to get metadata on myself, it works fine but when I try to execute the same URL from my python script I get an error.

The URL in the explorer that works is: (obscured)

`109566338825219?metadata=1&access_token=EAAUIU8EilCcBADPgUlZB2s5s69zGk2f1ZCCdASKb1CwowwIZATV8jMTyY0y16r9XU7ff19iI73FozfjtBjzjUiilsvOFhW133uCeTn3IHsGZApwmXYdvlcZBFxc6aT3UHgQxXJC7ZBKfEtZCjSHA8GCGUQbzg3PBiZAxZAMBQHlbZCXLwF8dhslGs3gLt3FNLZAZB4LhUUXyrlwiwVZBEjsLBMZB9VRByvwYZCFBIEZD`

My python script snippet is:

```
class FaceBookUserMetadata(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [HTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, uat, uid):
        
        
        logger.debug("getFacebookUserMetadata uat = %s ,uid = %s", uat, uid)
        access_token = uat #"EAADjbVVsAnABAE2e33q1R6LO2hVBZBIiQVuAsPY7AdhKzbgmWWz3fG8kZB9Y7eNre7uO5RWkMBZAHVagi8p4EMMcuFdgAVYVZCvZCiBjIDsasri5nZBWottP8dykL35FyWAfPZCMYSqqRZCSTNM0UWR06dIWalZAHhyKNgyIwFqKy2pz08jrAYsY2AfqIwUgtLzl7ZBcz1h6mTh6Q2hdHJS5XKLqXgNNHB9TZA9g1ZCW7546lzwn8pXqaXmsa8B2V5uP1HR8ZD"
        user_id = uid #"109566338825219"
    
        #here we execute the Facebook API 

        url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?metadata=1&access_token={access_token}"
        
        print("/api/metadata/ url = %s", url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        logger.debug('result = %s', response)
        result = response.json()

        logger.debug('result = %s', result)
        print("result = %s", result)

        return Response(result)
```

In the Explorer I get the metadata but in my code with same user id and same access token I get...

```
Error validating access token: Session has expired on
            Thursday, 01-Jun-23 21:00:00 PDT. The current time is Saturday, 03-Jun-23 16:56:14 PDT.&#x27;,
            &#x27;type&#x27;: &#x27;OAuthException&#x27;, &#x27;code&#x27;: 190, &#x27;error_subcode&#x27;: 463,
            &#x27;fbtrace_id&#x27;: &#x27;A6-Aw4RWj3hOIuaM2tNZYvk&#x27;}</li>
```

I have regenerated the access_token in the Graph API Explorer, with no change in behavior.

I also executed the same url with postman with the same user id and access token from the Explorer and get the metadata.

Here is the Graph API debug data

```
App ID  1416530633129895 : MyApp (id obfuscated)
Type    User
App-Scoped User ID
Learn More
109566338825219 : Michael Oliver (id obfuscated)
User last installed this app via API N/A
Issued  Unknown
Expires 1685840400 (in 55 minutes)
Data Access Expires 1693611049 (in about 3 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Unknown
Scopes  pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement
Granular Scopes
pages_show_list 
327913874657245 : My Co
pages_read_engagement   
327913874657245 : My Co
```

I don't see why my python script is throwing that error.

Comment: `&access_token{access_token}` Looks like you're missing an `=` in there...

Comment: Yes corrected the missing = but error is the same as shown here and not the view did break the uat and uid out properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the node id was my personal user id and not the app user id, at least when I noticed the difference and used the app user id, it worked.

Comment: FYI: The [`/me`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#me) shortcut always automatically resolves to the user or page the access token is for.